# "git fetch" remote fatal error

Tags: git, redmine, samba, cifs

In our company we have git repo that was created as local repo on network drive B:\. So all developers workstation have this network drive connected and all works fine.

But now I'm trying to run Redmine on VM. This VM has samba mounted path to git repo. To use git repo in Redmine i cloned our repo from samba mountet path with command `git clone --mirror *path_to_smb*`. This works fine. But when I try to call `git fetch --all` error `remote: fatal: Could not chdir to 'B:\': No such file or directory` ...etc. occurs.

How can I fix this error?

git.config:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    worktree = B:\
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[gui]
    wmstate = normal
    geometry = 856x377+176+176 313 169
[tgit]
    commitshowpatch = false
[remote “Remote_rep”]
    url =B:\\_remote\\remote.git\\
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/Remote_rep/*
[branch “master”]
    remote = Remote_rep
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Comment: Can you share your .git/config

Comment: [core]
 repositoryformatversion = 0
 filemode = false
 bare = false
 logallrefupdates = true
 worktree = B:\
 symlinks = false
 ignorecase = true
 hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[gui]
 wmstate = normal
 geometry = 856x377+176+176 313 169
[tgit]
 commitshowpatch = false
[remote “Remote_rep”]
 url =B:\\_remote\\remote.git\\
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/Remote_rep/*
[branch “master”]
 remote = Remote_rep
 merge = refs/heads/master

Comment: Just change the `url` for the remote to the correct path

Comment: I'm sorry, but i did not understand your question. This git.config is from remote git repo. VM's config has correct remote url: /mnt/smb/

Comment: The error is saying that the remote cannot access to `B:` are you sure the git server can access to `B:`?